# VBA - Search Column by Specific Name without Text box

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy specific columns by the column name and copy it to a new worksheet. I found this code online but I would like to have the cloumn names in the vba code instead of having a textbox pop up and me writing each one in at a time.

Sub copycolumns()

```
 Dim strColRng As String
 Dim strSheetName As String
 Dim intNoofCols As Integer
 Dim strColName() As String
 Dim strCurSheetName As String

 'To get the No. of Columns Available to Search
 intRng = 65

 'To get the No. of Columns to copy and paste
 intNoofCols = 10

 'To set size of the Array
 ReDim Preserve strColName(intNoofCols)
 For i = 0 To intNoofCols - 1
     'To Get the Column Name to Search
    strColName(i) = Array(Array("POS", "POS"), Array("Product Code", "Product Code"), Array("Product Name", "Product Name"), Array("Currency", "Currency"), Array("Nominal Source", "Nominal Source"), Array("Maturity Date", "Maturity Date"), Array("Nominal USD", "Nominal USD"), Array("BV Source", "BV Source"), Array("ISIN", "ISIN"), Array("Daily NII USD", "Daily NII USD"))
   ' InputBox("Enter the Column Name to Copy?", "Column Name")


 Next

'To get the Sheet Name to paste the content
 strSheetName = InputBox("Enter the Sheet Name to Paste?", "Sheet Name")

 'To store the Current Sheet Name where to copy

 strCurSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

 For j = 0 To intNoofCols - 1 'To get the Column Names from the Array

       For i = 1 To intRng

             'To Select the Sheet which column to copy
             Sheets(strCurSheetName).Select

               'Store the Cell Value
             strVal = Cells(1, i)

             'Check the Value with the User given column name
             If UCase(strVal) = UCase(Trim(strColName(j))) Then

                     'Select and Copy
                      Cells(1, i).Select
                      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                      Selection.Copy

                     'Select and Paste
                     Sheets(strSheetName).Select
                     Cells(1, j + 1).Select
                     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                '     ActiveSheet.Paste
              End If
       Next
  Next
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: That's already how it works.  Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, I tried it out. However, I am having problems with the strColName(i) = Array...  This continuies to give me the problem. Initially it was strColName(i) = InputBox("Enter the Column Name to Copy?", "Column Name")

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want the strColName variable to hold the array you defined, instead of the program looping and asking the user to fill the array? In that case, use:

```
Dim strColName() As String
strColName = Split("POS,Product Code,Product Name,Currency,Nominal Source,Maturity Date,Nominal USD,BV Source,ISIN,Daily NII USD", ",")
```

Problem is, you defined the strColName as an array of Strings, and you input arrays. Also, you defined the array inside the loop, so it will execute 10 times. You can delete the redim statement, because you define the number of members of the array when you make the array.

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time

```
'1 = DELETE all columns IN list
'2 = DELETE all columns NOT in list
'3 = MOVE all columns IN List to NEW Sheet
'4 = MOVE all columns NOT in List to NEW Sheet
'sSource = Source Sheet for Deleting or Moving To
'tTarget = Target Sheet for Moving Columns To
'n = offset the numer of columns when moving columns n = 0 for no offset
Sub MoveOrDelete()

  fDeleteOrMove 3, "MySheetNameSoure", "MySheetNameTarget", 0, Array("ColName1", "ColName2", "ColName3")

End Sub

'THIS IS THE FUNCTION FOR MOVE/DELETE
Sub fDeleteOrMove(cWhat As Integer, sSource As String, tTarget As String, n As Integer,    myList As Variant)
Dim wsS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsT As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LC As Long
Dim mycol As Long
Dim x

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sSource).Select
  Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sSource)  'Source Sheet for Deleting or Moving To
  Set wsT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tTarget)  'Target Sheet for Moving Columns To

'Get Last Row of "Source" Sheet
LC = wsS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For mycol = LC To 1 Step -1
    x = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    x = WorksheetFunction.match(Cells(1, mycol), myList, 0)

   Select Case cWhat
   Case 1
      'Delete all columns IN list
        If IsNumeric(x) Then wsS.Columns(mycol).EntireColumn.Delete
   Case 2
       'Delete all columns NOT in list
         If Not IsNumeric(x) Then wsS.Columns(mycol).EntireColumn.Delete
   Case 3
       'Move all columns IN List to NEW Sheet
         If IsNumeric(x) Then wsS.Columns(mycol).EntireColumn.Copy _
                                 Destination:=wsT.Columns(x).Offset(, n)
   Case 4
       'Move all columns NOT in List to NEW SheeT
         If Not IsNumeric(x) Then wsS.Columns(mycol).EntireColumn.Copy _
                                     Destination:=wsT.Columns(mycol).Offset(, n)
           'Delete the EMPTY columns that were not moved from "Target" sheet
             If IsNumeric(x) Then wsS.Columns(mycol).EntireColumn.Copy _
                                         Destination:=wsT.Columns(mycol).Offset(, n).Delete

  End Select
Next mycol
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tTarget).Select
End Sub
```